# Typescript using a union as a generic argument wrapped in a conditional

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Take the following deliberately simplified code example (my real use case is more complex, but the problem boils down to this):

```
type TArbitraryUnion = "a" | "b";

type TObjectWithGeneric<T> = {
    prop: T;
};

type TTypeWithConditional<T> = T extends string
    ? TObjectWithGeneric<T>
    : never;

type TTypeWithoutConditional<T> = TObjectWithGeneric<T>;

type TType1 = TTypeWithConditional<TArbitraryUnion>; // TObjectWithGeneric<"a"> | TObjectWithGeneric<"b">
type TType2 = TTypeWithoutConditional<TArbitraryUnion>; // {prop: TArbitraryUnion;}
```

`TType1` ends up becoming a union of generics, whereas `TType2` becomes a generic of the union.

Is there any way of creating the definition of `TTypeWithConditional` such that it becomes `TObjectWithGeneric<"a" | "b">` instead of `TObjectWithGeneric<"a"> | TObjectWithGeneric<"b">`?

I'm struggling to understand why `TType1` and `TType2` are ending up as different types. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using conditional types with generics, the condition acts distributively on union types. See the documentation on [Distributive Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).

As another example of how the distribution works, and which shows why it is important:

Suppose we modify `TArbitraryUnion` to be the union type `"a" | "b" | 1`. When we do this, `TType1` becomes `TObjectWithGeneric<"a"> | TObjectWithGeneric<"b">` (i.e. `{prop: "a" | "b"}`), and `TType2` remains `{prop: TArbitraryUnion}` (i.e. `{prop: "a" | "b" | 1}`). Since `TType2` does not use a conditional type, the condition does not need to be distributed among the type parameter, but it does need to be distributed among `TType1` because `1 extends string` falls into the false case (`never`).

Comment: Thanks for this! The distributive conditional docs shows that you can wrap either side of the extends with square brackets (`[T] extends [string]`) and this prevents the distributive behaviour. It works perfectly now.

Comment: @JamesFlight That will work in your provided case in the OP because `["a" | "b"] extends [string]` is true, but consider the case when `TArbitraryUnion` is `"a" | "b" | 1`: `TType1` will be `never` since `["a" | "b" | 1] extends [string]` is false. I would suggest not to rely on this method and to instead allow conditionals to distribute naturally unless you are sure that is what you want. Remember: `TObjectWithGeneric<"a"> | TObjectWithGeneric<"b">` is the same as `{prop: "a" | "b"}`, or rather `{prop: TArbitraryUnion}` in the OP.

Comment: You can find more information on why `TObjectWithGeneric<"a"> | TObjectWithGeneric<"b">` and `{prop: "a" | "b"}` are the same, in the [Type Compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) documentation. Essentially: TypeScript uses _structural_ typing and not _nominal_ typing.